# Time beetween +5/-5 minutes

Tags: date, ksh

Im trying to write a script (ksh) which will check if time is right (+/- 5 minutes)

```
echo "$(cat /home/chojtom/Tomek/Log.txt | sed -e 's:\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\([-]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\([-]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\([[:space:]]\)\(.*\):\7:g')" | sed     -e "s:[:]::g" > "/home/chojtom//Time.csv"
```

This is variable Time in format : HHMMSS

```
if [ $(Time) -ge  date  "+%H%M%S" -d "5 min ago" ]; then
echo "Wrong hour"

else


echo "Date Correct"
```

but on this step i get message 

`./test.sh[45]: Time: not found [No such file or directory]
./test.sh[45]: [: date: unknown operator
DATE CORRECT`

the file Time.csv is there with line HHMMSS.

Cant figure it out, whats wrong with date operator in IF.
Can please someone help?

UPDATE
and i have noticed that command

```
Year="/home/chojtom/year.csv"

$(cat /home/chojtom/Tomek/Log.txt | sed -e 's:\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\([-]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\([-]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\(.*\):\1:g')" > $Year
```

does not save output to the file

Comment: Ok, should be $Time, the shell sees the file now, but still - date :unknow operator error pops out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try evaluating/running the **date** command:

```
if [ ${Time} -ge $(date  "+%H%M%S" -d "5 min ago") ]; then
echo "Wrong hour"
else
echo "Date Correct"
fi
```

Though I'm guessing this is still a work in progress since it should print 'Wrong hour' even if ${Time} is more than 5 minutes old.

Comment: Yes, it's in progress but i got stuck on the date operator in If, let me check and comeback to you

Comment: Works!, great thank you.
Still got problem with output save - post UPDATE

Comment: As for the new/second issue ... I'd suggest opening a new question (since there are 2 different issues) ... and provide the contents of the Log.txt file plus the full output from the echo/cat/sed command [any (error) messages? does file get created? what is placed in file?]